# Projects in Workspace having a jar on their Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse

How to know which project Class-path has a reference for a particular jar.  Actually One of the class I am using is there in multiple versions jars and hence giving problem during run time. I just want to remove the previous version from the class path of respective projects.

There are lot of Projects and Jars in each project, so I don't want to open each projects Build Path and look for the Jar. Is there any shortcut.

Comment: about time you use maven :) If you are, it will show you the dependency heirarchy. which will show you duplicate jars because of transitive dependencies

Comment: Thanks. yes i am using Maven. How to see Dependency Hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the clarification on the comment. Open the `pom.xml` file. and navigate to the `dependency heirarchy` tab. This will show you all the dependencies for your project.
When you do see a repetitive jar file (downloaded as part of a transitive dependency) you have a choice.

1. Either remove your own dependency definition from the `pom.xml`

   or
2. Right click on the jar (transitive) and select exclude.

You can also alternatively check your dependency tree through the command line.

For example, to find out why Commons Collections 2.0 is being used by the Maven Dependency Plugin, we can execute the following in the project's directory:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```

Here is the official [Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

### EDIT : Straight from the Maven dependency plugin page. I thought it would make the answer more descriptive rather than clicking several links.

A very good example shown on the official page about resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree

For example, to find out why Commons Collections 2.0 is being used by the Maven Dependency Plugin, we can execute the following in the project's directory:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections

The verbose flag instructs the dependency tree to display conflicting dependencies that were omitted from the resolved dependency tree. In this case, the goal outputs:

[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile
Thus we can see that Commons Collections 2.0 was chosen over 2.1 since it is nearer, and by default Maven resolves version conflicts with a nearest-wins strategy.

More specifically, in verbose mode the dependency tree shows dependencies that were omitted for: being a duplicate of another; conflicting with another's version and/or scope; and introducing a cycle into the dependency tree.
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I am almost there to resolve this. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just Do a search for that previous version in all .classpath files.

Execute Dependency:Tree for your Maven project and get a Tree of Dependencies. Search for your jar in this tree.